# Spitting string into array with specific delimer

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Would like to find a way to split a string info a array in as shown below. The delimer is always in the format:

```
string + int + int + int

P000 or P000 + P000  or P000 + P000 + P000
```

String:

```
P210 Får inte utsättas för värme, heta ytor, gnistor, öppen låga eller andra antändningskällor. Rökning förbjuden. P220 Hålls/förvarad åtskilt från kläder/brännbara material. P273 Undvik utsläpp till miljön. P280 Använd skyddshandskar/ skyddskläder/ ögonskydd/ ansiktsskydd. P333 + P313 Vid hudirritation eller utslag: Sök läkarhjälp. P403 + P235 Förvaras på väl ventilerad plats. Förvaras svalt. P403 + P235 + P236 Förvaras på väl ventilerad plats. Förvaras svalt. I mörker.
```

Desired output:

```
P210 Får inte utsättas för värme, heta ytor, gnistor, öppen låga eller andra antändningskällor. Rökning förbjuden. 
P220 Hålls/förvarad åtskilt från kläder/brännbara material. 
P273 Undvik utsläpp till miljön. 
P280 Använd skyddshandskar/ skyddskläder/ ögonskydd/ ansiktsskydd. 
P333 + P313 Vid hudirritation eller utslag: Sök läkarhjälp.
P403 + P235 Förvaras på väl ventilerad plats. Förvaras svalt
P403 + P235 + P236 Förvaras på väl ventilerad plats. Förvaras svalt. I mörker.
```

.

Comment: I was trying to do this by looping the string and when finding character "P" getting the index of this, if the following two character was integers this would indicate that a new position in the array should be added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest *matching*, not *splitting* (since you want delimeters being *included*):

```
  string source = "P210 Får inte utsättas ... Förvaras svalt. I mörker.";
  ...
  string pattern = @"(?<index>P[0-9]{3}( \+ P[0-9]{3}){0,2})(?<text>.+?)(?=(P[0-9]{3})|$)";

  string[] lines = Regex.Matches(source, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that you can use `\d` to avoid having to write `[0-9]`.

Comment: @pie3636: `\d` is *not* equal to `[0-9]`, e.g.`\d` includes persian digits as well: `۱`

Comment: Thank you, I had absolutely no idea. After looking it up, in some other languages like JavaScript it seems to only include `[0-9]`.

Comment: Or split with `(?=(?<!P\d+\s*\+\s*)P\d+)`. Also, `\d` *is equal* to `[0-9]` if you use `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag.

Answer (score 2):

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!\+ )(P\d\d\d)", "\n$1");
```

This will work in most situations, unless there is a possibility that the text `"+ "` can be found before a group with a `Pxxx`; for example `text + P123` will not split. While this is arguably not 100% failproof, it might be enough in your case, and is easy to read/understand.

What it does is look for strings matching `P[digit][digit][digit]` that are not following a `"+ "`, and it then splits there.

Note that you can replace the `\d\d\d` with `\d{3}`.

[Test it online](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/FeralCompanionablePapaJimmy)

Regex explanation:

```
(?<!                 Do not match anything following this text (this is called a negative lookbehind)
    \+               A plus sign and a space
       )
        (P\d\d\d)    A P and 3 digits, parentheses allow us to "save" this group for later

\n$1                 Replace with a newline character and the first group within parentheses (not that the "do not match" part is not included in this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating each character from string. You can determine whether character is int or string using Char.IsDigit and Char.IsChar methods.

Comment: Yes, or use a regex. This is not an answer, but a comment. You can earn 50 points necessary to obtain a commenting privilege easily by editing questions or *answering* 2-3 questions well.